# How to change the value of a variable on button press (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to make my first Android App but have come across an error that I ave no idea how to fix.
I want to change the value of a variable called buttonPressed when an image button is pressed, this is the code I have so far:
    boolean buttonPressed  = false;

```
ImageButton button_a=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.blue_a_button);

//a function to play the audio when button_a is pressed
button_a.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        player=MediaPlayer.create(GameActivity.this,R.raw.a);

        player.start();

        buttonPressed = true;

    }
});
```

However, when I type this into Android Studio I get the error: "variable "buttonPressed" is acccessed from inner class, needs to be declared final"

And if I make the variable final, then the value cannot be changed. What should I do?

Cheers :)

Comment: *What should I do?* learn java basics ... in short buttonPressed seems to be local variable in some other function ... and can't  be used in inner class (inplace View.OnClickListener implementation)

Comment: buttonPressed should be member of Acitivity or Fragment

Comment: I think all the answers and the question were marked with a -1 by someone or something... :P +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just declare your variable as:

```
  public  class <Your Class Name> extends Activity{

       private boolean buttonPressed;
```

Comment: the version WITHOUT final is ok

Comment: why -1 again? Hey troll go to your hole! hahahahaha

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access that variable on button press, then you should declare it as a class variable

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Boolean buttonPressed = false;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //-->>>>> If you will declare the variable here, then it has to be final..

    final Button button_a = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_a);

    //a function to play the audio when button_a is pressed
    button_a.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            player=MediaPlayer.create(GameActivity.this,R.raw.a);
            player.start();
            buttonPressed = true;
        }
    });
    }
}
```

Comment: no, it is not ... the OP used local and in this answer we have *you should declare it as a class variable* ... still code is not showing that

Comment: its an inner class, it requires the variable to be final.

Comment: I see, my mistake. I should go home now

Comment: http://ideone.com/OSw6Vo <= small example why it cannot be final ... why cannot be not final but local: http://ideone.com/ctLG3d and the solution from this and Elenasys answers : http://ideone.com/fP0bxU

Comment: No i know. I was still taking it as function variable. The ans was correct but not the solution.

Comment: also there is final local variable solution too: http://ideone.com/WSGCvm ... but it also means that button state will not be accessible outside outer function (Activity contructor in this example)